# Unity and Gnome 3 Lock Screen

Tags: unity, gnome, lock

I installed Ubuntu Unity 14.10. Recently, I added the Gnome 3 shell so that I can run both. At my login screen, I can choose which one to log in to. I have noticed that when I choose to log in with Gnome 3, that I am unable to lock the screen. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can overcome this if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reconfiguring the gdm by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

You will see a number of display managers.
[image: Screenshot after the command]
Try selecting one of them and see if it helps. Don't worry, you can change this anytime using the same command.

Comment: Thanks! Changing to gdm allowed me to lock from the Gnome Shell.

Comment: Happy to help. Kindly choose this answer as best or whatever it says. It helps. :)